# Cannot scroll when cursor is on fixed menu

Tags: javascript, css

I got some small annoying problem which I cant fix , I got Fixed menu when will scroll down and everything is ok , but when I will point cursor on this menu and try to scroll on my mouse then nothing happens and I cant scroll , I need to move cursor from menu then I can again scroll website. Any Idea what happening ?

Comment: Post some kind of code and demonstration. Else there's nothing for us to help you debug on.